# Custom option displaying Product Price on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, price, custom-options

There are custom options displaying on product view page. But custom options are displaying product price. **Custom option should display their own price.**
[image]

Comment: You need to display custom options with price. are you added price per custom option in admin side right?

Comment: Yes I have added price for custom option. But it is showing product price as displayed in image.

Comment: I have checked on the product view page. But it is work fine. Have added extension or any custom code?

Comment: Atleast for this functionality I have not added any extension.. But I do not know about custom code. Can you tell me from where this price is coming?

Comment: but i checked in default magento.1.9 and it is work fine. Can you please give product url?

Comment: I think you are customize some code. Please check your default magento

Comment: But I am not getting from where this price is coming